# Indexing Properties with accurate keyof typeof type

Tags: typescript, compiler-warnings

Why can I not index variable `y` with the keys from `x`?

```
interface A {
    a: string;
    b: number;
    e: boolean;
};
declare let x: A;
declare let y: A;
let t: keyof typeof x;
for (t in x) {
    y[t] = x[t];
}
```

On the assignment I get this error: `Type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)`

Comment: @jcalz Interesting. I didn't realize it would be reproducible at that level. I guess my issue is more fundamental than I thought. I edited the post.

Comment: @jcalz Ah, yep. Done.

Comment: This is essentially [ms/TS#32693](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32693).  See that and the linked questions/answers for more information.

Comment: It is, and it's somewhat comforting to know I wasn't crazy, and it is actually a missing/omitted feature in TypeScript.

Comment: See [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mLJKkw) for more info.  Yes, this is definitely a pain point of TS.  You might want to go to that issue and give it a .  I think it only has a handful of upvotes and so it might not even really be on anyone's radar to implement.